How can I remove overlapping points on a grid in geometry nodes?
I am trying to generate a heterostructures of a crystal using geometry nodes. As a starting point I have "core" crystal which consist of red (anions) and white (cations) atoms.

Then I want to grow a secondary crystal on the periphery of the "core" with same structure parameters but different atoms (dark blue and yellow). This secondary structure is called "crown". Then I remove the overlapping atoms of "core" and "crown" using Geometry Proximity and Math (Grater Than) nodes as Selection in Instances on Points node. Until here I have no problem.


Then I grow a third structure "shell" all around the structure (either "core" or "core" plus "crown") with magenta (anions) and cyan (cations) atoms. I can remove the overlapping cations of shell and previous structure. When I try to do it on anions of shell with the same approach, the operation remove all the anions of shell in z direction.


So where are my magenta atoms above and below the "core" or "core"+"crown" structure? :)


Putting a Realize Instances node just solved it :)

